# Whats wrong with my SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I had to edit a stored procedure to and add the ability to sort out results by department. After editing, I received an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   acc_qry_profit_loss_this_year_by_dept, Line 543 Column
>   '#tmp_rsl.department' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I believe that the error isn't at line 543 or maybe its just my eyes.
Here is the code starting from line 485 to 557:

```
-- Blank line
  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT 0,'','' as acc_code,'' as acc_name,1,0,0,0,0,'BLANK_LINE' as rsl_type,0 as show_line

    --OI    Other Income
  SET @rsl_acc_type='OI'
  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_credit,0)-ISNULL(yr_debit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_credit,0)-ISNULL(ly_debit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_credit,0)-ISNULL(mn_debit,0),ISNULL(lm_credit,0)-ISNULL(lm_debit,0),
    (CASE WHEN attribute=99 THEN 'CAT_HEAD' WHEN attribute=0 THEN 'FOLDER' ELSE 'DETAIL' END) as rsl_type,0
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel=1 

  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_credit,0)-ISNULL(yr_debit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_credit,0)-ISNULL(ly_debit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_credit,0)-ISNULL(mn_debit,0),ISNULL(lm_credit,0)-ISNULL(lm_debit,0),
    (CASE WHEN attribute=99 THEN 'CAT_HEAD' WHEN attribute=0 THEN 'FOLDER' ELSE 'DETAIL' END) as rsl_type,0
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel<>1 order by department,acc_code

  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','' as acc_code,'' as acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_credit,0)-ISNULL(yr_debit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_credit,0)-ISNULL(ly_debit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_credit,0)-ISNULL(mn_debit,0),ISNULL(lm_credit,0)-ISNULL(lm_debit,0),
    'CAT_SUMM' as rsl_type,1
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel=1

  --EX  Expenses
  SET @rsl_acc_type='EX'
  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_debit,0)-ISNULL(yr_credit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_debit,0)-ISNULL(ly_credit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_debit,0)-ISNULL(mn_credit,0),ISNULL(lm_debit,0)-ISNULL(lm_credit,0),
    (CASE WHEN attribute=99 THEN 'CAT_HEAD' WHEN attribute=0 THEN 'FOLDER' ELSE 'DETAIL' END) as rsl_type,0
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel=1 

  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_debit,0)-ISNULL(yr_credit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_debit,0)-ISNULL(ly_credit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_debit,0)-ISNULL(mn_credit,0),ISNULL(lm_debit,0)-ISNULL(lm_credit,0),
    (CASE WHEN attribute=99 THEN 'CAT_HEAD' WHEN attribute=0 THEN 'FOLDER' ELSE 'DETAIL' END) as rsl_type,0
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel<>1 order by department,acc_code

  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','' as acc_code,'' as acc_name,acclevel,
    ISNULL(yr_debit,0)-ISNULL(yr_credit,0),
    ISNULL(ly_debit,0)-ISNULL(ly_credit,0),
    ISNULL(mn_debit,0)-ISNULL(mn_credit,0),ISNULL(lm_debit,0)-ISNULL(lm_credit,0),
    'CAT_SUMM' as rsl_type,1
  FROM #tmp_acc_list WHERE acctype=@rsl_acc_type AND acclevel=1

  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','NP' as acc_code,'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
    'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,1
  FROM #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
```

So, is there anyone who could point out the possible error if it exists within the part of code the I have shown?

I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: The last query has aggregated columns, but no Group By.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last query

```
   SELECT 
         0,
         department,
         department_name,
         '',
          'NP' as acc_code,
         'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
         'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,
         1 
   FROM 
     #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
```

is the problem. You use columns like 'department' without any aggregate and then you have columns computed by an aggregate (like sum). You can not mix those colums. Either you have no aggregates, all aggregates or the columns without any aggregate must be part of your grouping, like this:

```
   SELECT 
         0,
         department,
         department_name,
         '',
          'NP' as acc_code,
         'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
         SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
         'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,
         1 
   FROM 
     #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
   GROUP BY department, department_name
```

Answer (score 1):

line numbers in errors are often misleading especially for stored procs. it can be a good indication of what part of the query the error is in (esp if there are hundreds of lines) but you should focus on the description of the error.

> Column '#tmp_rsl.department' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

the select list contains a field (department) that isnt contained in the aggregate function or the group by clause.
theres only one query with an aggregate function and it also doesnt have a group by clause.

```
  INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,
    yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
  SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','NP' as acc_code,'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
    'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,1
  FROM #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
```

the SUM part of this query is an aggregate function.
you need to ad a GROUP BY after the FROM.
will probably need a few department, dept_name,
acc_code is included in the aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some thing like this in your query...

```
select EmpId, count(LocationId)
from Employee
```

OR some thing opposite to it

```
select EmpId, LocationId
from Employee
Group by EmpId
```

In both the cases the following error will be raised

> Column 'Employee.EmpId' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

And if you see carefully your query you have some aggregate functions used like SUM (in your last query) etc.

Comment: I only added the 'department' and 'department_name' within the INSERT SELECT statements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of aggregate functions (SUM) in the final insert statement. you might find [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx) article useful..

In the meantime..

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','NP' as acc_code,'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
  'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,1
FROM #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_rsl(acc_id,department,department_name,parent_code,acc_code,description,acclevel,yr_balance,ly_balance,mn_balance,lm_balance,rsl_type,show_line)
SELECT 0,department,department_name,'','NP' as acc_code,'NET PROFIT/(LOSS)' as acc_name,1,
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*yr_balance ELSE yr_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX' THEN -1*ly_balance ELSE ly_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*mn_balance ELSE mn_balance END)),
  SUM((CASE WHEN acc_code='CS' OR acc_code='EX'  THEN -1*lm_balance ELSE lm_balance END)),
  'CAT_NETPROFIT' as rsl_type,1
FROM #tmp_rsl WHERE rsl_type='CAT_HEAD'
GROUP BY department,department_name
```